# Matlab Contour Drawing

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I want to draw a contour for a given function.

My function is `f = transpose([5;5])*[X;Y] + transpose([X;Y])*[2 3; 4 2]*[X;Y]/2;` and I want to draw the contour for values of X and Y from -100 to 100. How can I do that? When I create a `linspace` for X and Y, I get a dimension match error. I can get a single value for the function but can't draw a plot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dimension match error, means dimensions do not match the rules of algebra.

Assume:

```
X = -100:100;
Y = -100:100;
```

`size(transpose([X;Y])*[2 3; 4 2]*[X;Y]/2)`
`ans =`
`201   201`

`size([X*5;Y*5])`
`ans =`
`2   201`

You can't sum 2x201 matrix with 201x201 matrix.

The following code works (size of f is 2x201):

```
f = [X*5;Y*5] + (([X;Y])'*[2 3; 4 2])'.*[X;Y]/2;
```

I'am not sure if the above formula gives the result you wanted.